# Customize swagger example xml request

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, request, swagger

I use java and I have some entity that contains a List of another entity. But swagger has built incorrect request.

[image]

but I need this:

[image]

How I can customize swagger request?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/2047

I found this. but it didn't work for me. I hope it will be useful for someone